# Dashboards in Salesforce Customer Community

Tags: community, reporting, customer-community, dashboard, community-builder

I know that it is possible to add Reports/Dashboards to Customer Community if you have Customer Community Plus License.

We are using Service Cloud and I was wondering if it will be possible to add the reports or charts to customer community such that the user logged in will only see the data for their company's cases. If yes please let me know how this can be achieved.

Comment: please refer to the [H&T portal](https://help.salesforce.com/home) for these kinds of questions, [Create a Dashboard for Your Community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_create_dashboard_for_cm.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

Comment: btw, welcome to SFSE, please take some time to visit [ask] and take the [tour] to get familiar with the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following articles to do so :

1. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_analytics_limitations.htm&type=5
2. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_create_dashboard_for_cm.htm&type=5
3. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_view_dashboards.htm&type=5

I hope above links were helpful to you.

Comment: In reviewing your answer...
Please extract the relevant parts of those linked articles of content and add them to your answer, so that they answer the question without the articles, but leave the articles as a reference.

Doing this makes the answer more directly useful, and more searchable and links are there to back up your answer.
just linking articles and walking away could get you a down vote on SE.
SE is not the same as Salesforce Developer Forum, more effort must be given to Questions and answers.

I hope this helps, and I can re-review and consider recommending it or upvoting.